# What is the polygon pour and power plane for in a PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, pcb-layers

I am newly in PCB design.  Can any one explain me what polygon pours and power planes are used for in Altium PCB, or give me a link that explains it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Altium. Red-herring. Google ground planes and their benefits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A polygon pour is use to make, typically larger than a trace, arbitrary shapes in copper.

A power plane is usually an internal layer, that is "solid" copper. Typically it is used as either the ground return and/or the power rail. Usually there will be two power planes, one for ground return and another for the power rail.

I use the word typically and usually because, it's just metal, so you can do whatever you want with it. Split planes are an example of this. Also, I've used both polygon pours and split planes to route motor return currents separate from the other copper planes on the PCB.

**Per the comments:**
A large area of copper can be used for several things:

1. Thermal Heatsinking
2. Ground plane
3. Power plane
4. Shielding
5. Low inductance path between several components
6. High current path between components

Comment: Ok...thank you for your help...But i have read that polygon pour is used also for ground ...is this true?

Comment: @user255471: planes are used when you want all or most of a layer to be copper.  Polygon pours are used to fill parts of a copper layer, where most of the layer is used for signal tracks.  Polygon pours are usually grounded, but may be used for other things where a large area of copper is required.

Comment: Ok..thank you...your answer  is very acceptable for me to understand....do you mind to tell me when a large area of copper is required in a pcb..?... i am very thankful for you...

Comment: @user255471 See the updated answer

Comment: Ok..thank you sir..i am very thankful